# Kivy: overwriting properties in subclass

Tags: python, subclass, kivy

What is the correct way of overwriting a property defined in a kivy class?
Suppose I have a class

```
class A(Widget):
    prop = ObjectProperty(SomeDefaultObject)
    ...
```

In a subclass, I want to overwrite the property with a different default object. Is the following the right way to do it?

```
class B(A):
    prop = ObjectProperty(SomeOtherDefaultObject)
```

Should this be handled in a different manner? Does this double declaration interfere with the underlying magic (i.e. on change events, validation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is perfectly okay.  I wouldn't recommend anything else.